# Why are games launched with .deb package Steam not hardware accelerated?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, nvidia, deb, steam

I just distro hopped from Fedora to Tuxedo OS, and I’m encountering a problem I remember having on some other Ubuntu based distributions. Steam games do not have hardware acceleration when launched via the .deb package version of Steam (i.e. the one that installs via apt), or don’t launch at all. The flatpak version of Steam does not have this problem, but I don’t want to use that because it has some other quirks I don’t want. I have NVidia graphics, and the drivers auto-installed correctly with Tuxedo OS. I can confirm this because the GPU memory meter I have on the panel works correctly (it hasn’t whenever the drivers were not installed/working properly).

Notably, Steam is set to start with the system (IDK if this was a setting preserved with my home folder or not), but it doesn’t seem to be doing so.

Comment: How do you launch a .deb package?

Comment: @OrganicMarble you don’t exactly launch a .deb package. You install it with dpkg or a package manager based on that, most of which automatically download it from a repository (kind of like an App Store), and in this case it puts the Steam binary onto PATH among other configuration stuff. A .deb package is a software installer, built to work with the Debian package system, which Debian’s child distros typically use (Ubuntu does).

Comment: So, you mean games *installed* from .deb packages.

Comment: @OrganicMarble no, I mean Steam installed from the deb package on the official Ubuntu repos. I have edited to clarify this in the question body.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The games in question are installed within Steam. It's Steam that is installed either via the official .deb package found by apt, or via the Flatpak on Flathub.

Comment: Thanks, I finally get what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it's under Ubuntu, but in Debian you also need to change your system to multiarch, using  `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and also install additional packages `apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers libglx-mesa0:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` to make it work. https://wiki.debian.org/Steam

Comment: @paladin I just distro hopped again to Linux Mint because of other major problems, so I don’t know if that’s the answer. However, those packages are installed by default on Mint, and the problem is not here. That may have been the issue, since I think I remember seeing them install in Tuxedo OS, but they were not the I 386 versions as I recall.

Comment: You usually want to install both version, as there are still 32bit games available on Steam which need those i386 libraries.